# substr_count(): Offset not contained in string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this annoying error (see title) coming in on the vps server at this line of code of a plugin:

```
$distance = substr_count($image_path, '/', $offset) + substr_count($content_path, '/', $offset);
```

The plugin fetches feeds and on the vps it brings in a wrong image for a certain feed. The same plugin with same settings works without errors on staging site on a shared hosting. The php version 7.2 and php settings are the same on both servers.

What could be wrong?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: You should compare the paths and offsets on both servers - I think they aren't the same

Comment: @arisalsaila Check the title of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a server misconfiguration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check `$image_path`, `$content_path` and `$offset`.
I think, they not the same on both servers.
You could use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php) for this case:

```
file_put_contents('debug.txt', var_export($image_path, true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('debug.txt', var_export($content_path, true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('debug.txt', var_export($offset, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I tried this and on both servers I got same result: NULLNULLNULL

Comment: So need to filter $image_path, $content_path and $offset before